# API key - in content or header

Tags: api

Working on an API at the moment and just wanted to gather opinions on where the best place to transmit the API key should be. I know that is shouldn't go in the URL, this leaves the request header or the message body.

If I put it in the header I can come up with a generic method for pulling it out that can be used across all services, however the spec I've been handed wants it in the body (ie in a JSON string included as part of the serialized object in the POST body).

Comment: Note as well that not all request types should have a body and if you want to validate a request without a body that the key will need to be in the header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In HTTP, there is a `Authorization` header for that.

While it is usually used to provide users' credentials, in a case of an API, it can contain the ID of the client and the corresponding API key.

There are several benefits:

- Support from different frameworks. Many frameworks will expect `Authorization` header in order to do authentication. Not using it will force to write additional code to feed those frameworks with custom values.
- Support from different tools. For instance CURL.
- Less “WTF where do I find/put this API key?!” from new developers joining the team (or developers designing new clients for your API).
- You can then use HTTP status code definitions such as `401 Unauthorized`, [for which](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2):

  > The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field [...] The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field.

Moving it to the body of the request can become quickly painful. Most frameworks and tools don't make it very straightforward to add a body to a request, which may make your API more difficult than it needs to be.